# Present a View modally from a tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, popup, uitabbarcontroller

How can I present a View modally from a tab bar controller so that the view goes over the actual one?

I want to build a view with a camera. Something just like "WhatsApp" or "Instagram" where there is a button in the middle that the user can click and the camera view shows up.

Additionally, the user should move the tab he was before when the close button was clicked.

This is how my ViewController is connected to the TabBarController:
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've had to implement something similar in an app I'm currently building, it's relatively straightforward to do, you need to implement a delegate method of `UITabBarController` in order to achieve this.

The delegate method you need to implement is: 
`tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool`

Returning false from this method will stop the tab controller from selecting your tab, you then just need to implement your own logic to present the `UIViewController` programatically.

Here's an example:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    // If your view controller is emedded in a UINavigationController you will need to check if it's a UINavigationController and check that the root view controller is your desired controller (or subclass the navigation controller)
    if viewController is YourViewControllerClass {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboardID") as? YourViewControllerClass {
            controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        return false
    }

    // Tells the tab bar to select other view controller as normal
    return true
}
```

I've not tested the above code as my implementation is slightly different and has more variables. The general principle is the same.

Let me know how you get on and I'll update the answer if necessary.

Comment: I used your code and it is still not working how it would like it to work. So created a new class for my TabBarController and pasted your code in there. Is that what u meant? And which class should I write instead of YourViewControllerClass? Maybe you can have a look at my picture, which I linked in my original post.

Comment: Hey, you will need to subclass your `UITabBarController` and implement the `UITabBarDelegate` on this class. In `viewDidLoad` you will need to do `self.delegate = self` then the above method will be fired when you try to select a tab across the bottom. `YourViewControllerClass` is the class associated with the view controller on your storyboard (the one on the left). You will need to subclass `UIViewController` and apply this class to that view controller.

Comment: Yeey! It works. Thanks a lot for your help. I forgot about the self.delegate = self. Now if I want to close it with a button, how can I manage to get back to the ViewController is was right before?

Comment: I'm glad it works! So in `YourViewControllerClass` you just need to bind an action to a button and call `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`. This will just dismiss the view controller and your `UITabBarController` should still be on the tab it was on when you left it if you returned false in the delegate method.

Comment: Here's how to do it if your using programmatic views: https://gist.github.com/wavecos/4dcb1410a41b9dd521cb

Comment: if you have navigation controller before the view controller. 1 :  creat new file, 2 : class it with navigation vc , 3 : use that class name as `YourViewControllerClass`

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you are conforming to [UITabBarControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate), you could implement:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

    // here, you should edit "0" to be matched with your selected item
    // for instance, if there is 5 items and the desired item is in the middle, the compared value should be "2"
    if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0 {

        // simply, you will need to get the desired view controller and persent it:
        let desiredStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let desiredViewController = desiredStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboard id")

        present(desiredViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: I made the relationship segue directly in the storyboard, so the tab bar item is created automatically. So I already have a view connected to the tab bar controller, however, I don't want to use it because I don't want to switch in another view. I want it to pop up. What should I do?

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Go check my original post. My problem is that instead of presenting the view modally it switches to the view because of the TabBarController. And it does so because I implemented it like this, but now I am asking how to not switch the view but show modally. So that it pops up over my actual view.

Comment: Well, if I got it right, what I have posted should does what are you asking about. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. But anyway, it works now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Glad t help. Btw, please don't forget to accept an answer :)

Comment: VERY NICE! Helped a lot thank you. @JoshSchärer you need accept this answer. Works perfectly in Swift 4, Xcode 10+

Comment: This does work for Swift 4.2 , infact one of the simplest solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
    let modalVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerIdentifier") 
    modalVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    modalVC.modalPresentationStyle = .full or .overfullscreen // please check which of the options work
    self.present(modalVC, animated: true, completion: {

    })
```